# Send Email is going to JUNK when provided the display name

Tags: vb.net, smtp

I am sending email using smtp client from office 365 account . below is the code that i am using to send the email. The email is going to the JUNk folder in outlook and also the From address is showing as `EmployeeName@ <yyy.com noreply@xxx.com>` instead of `EmployeeName@yyy.com <noreply@xxx.com>`. So can any one please give me any solution to fix this issue

```vb
Dim client As New SmtpClient()
Dim message As New MailMessage()
Dim par_ReplyName As String = "noreply@xxx.com"
Dim par_ReplyAddress As String = "EmployeeName@yyy.com"

message.From = New MailAddress(par_ReplyName, par_ReplyAddress)
message.ReplyToList.Add(par_ReplyAddress)
message.Priority = MailPriority.Normal
message.Subject = "Test Email"
message.Body = "some HTML content"
message.IsBodyHtml = True

client.Host = "smtp.office365.com"
client.Port = 587
client.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(smtpUser, smtpPassword)
client.EnableSsl = True
client.Send(message)
```

Comment: Um, perhaps take a look at the documentation for the `MailAddress` constructor and pay close attention to the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you're using the `MailAddress` constructor:

```
message.From = New MailAddress(par_ReplyName, par_ReplyAddress)
```

Here's the declaration for that constructor from the documentation:

```
'Declaration 
Public Sub New ( _
    address As String, _
    displayName As String _
)
```

Do you see anything amiss there, like maybe you have the arguments the wrong way around?